# parse two-dimensional array string to .net

Tags: c#, .net

i'm retrieving the following data from the Census API in string format.

```
[["NAME","B01001_001E","state","county","tract","block group"],
["Block Group 1, Census Tract 1.10, Franklin County, Ohio","1165","39","049","000110","1"],
["Block Group 2, Census Tract 1.10, Franklin County, Ohio","1038","39","049","000110","2"],
["Block Group 3, Census Tract 1.10, Franklin County, Ohio","551","39","049","000110","3"],
["Block Group 4, Census Tract 1.10, Franklin County, Ohio","881","39","049","000110","4"]]
```

What would you consider is the best way to parse this data into a List or perhaps even an DataTable where we use the column names?

I'm now writing my own parser, (using split, etc.) but I'm hoping there is an easier way that directly parses the data for you. A JSON serializer won't work as it isn't json data (no key, value pairs).

Thanks!

Comment: That's csv! Split by `","`

Comment: it isn't quite CSV due to the brackets, but that is helpful, thanks!

Comment: No, don't split by anything yourself. Use a dedicated parser for this format.

Comment: ANTLR for example.

Comment: @fubo If he just splits by `','` then he'll end up splitting the contents of the first string in each row.

Comment: @fubo That would still just produce a one dimensional array rather than the table-like structure that he or she is looking for.  _If_ you were to write your own parser for this (which you shouldn't), you should at least split the entire string into a tree of arrays which would then be split for data.

Comment: @LukeSamuel i wrote my thoughts into a answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) *(After all, [it's valid JSON](http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator/cba984d5))*:

First, create a class that will represent your entities:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int B01001_001E { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public int County { get; set; }
    public int Tract { get; set; }
    public int BlockGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize your data:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string[]>>(data);

IEnumerable<Entity> entities = 
records.Skip(1) // We skip the header row
.Select(r => new Entity()
{
    Name = r[0],
    B01001_001E = Convert.ToInt32(r[1]),
    State = Convert.ToInt32(r[2]),
    County = Convert.ToInt32(r[3]),
    Tract = Convert.ToInt32(r[4]),
    BlockGroup = Convert.ToInt32(r[5])
});
```

Comment: thank you, i was under the assumption that it wasn't a valid JSON dataset. it is. I was having some problems with the JSON parser earlier on, that made me assume that was the case.